# CodeDeploy agent install Error :: /usr/bin/env : ruby Not found

Tags: ruby, centos, installation, aws-codecommit

I am trying to install codeDeploy agent on CentOS6.

What I did

```
$ > wget https://aws-codedeploy-ap-northeast-2  .s3.amazonaws.com/latest/install
$ > chmod +x ./install
$ > sudo ./install auto
```

Not found ruby error occurs, So I installed ruby `2.4.2` via tar file. (executable file located in `/usr/local/bin`)

After that when I try `sudo ./install auto`, It returns error message

```
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
```

When I open `install` file which download via `wget`, it starts with `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`.

I change this to `#! /usr/local/bin ruby` than it returns `sudo: unable to execute ./install: Permission denied` without asking password.

Is there any step I forgot or extra job to escape this problem?
 Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try symlinking the ruby installation to /use/bin/ruby and then run the installer. If the symlink is in place you shouldn't need to update the shebang in install script.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer would be a solution. However in my case, I just changed ruby install version.